# How to print multiple slices as one slice?

Tags: go, slice

In this Golang code, I have a variable called `developers` which is equal to two slices. I want them to be equal to one slice as shown in the required result.

Although I could do it by writing it in a single slice like this `{"first developer", "second developer"},` but I want to write them separately and print them as one but to be considered as multiple entities like this `[[first developer second developer]...]`

**Given result**

```
[[first developer] [second developer] [first project second project] [third project forth project]]
```

**Required result**

```
[[first developer second developer] [first project second project] [third project forth project]]
```

**Code**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    developers := [][]string{
        {"first developer"},
        {"second developer"},
    }
    var data [][]string
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        data = append(data, developers[i])
    }
    data = append(data, [][]string{
        {"first project", "second project"},
        {"third project", "forth project"},
    }...)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks first you want to "flatten" the `developers` 2D slice (`[][]string`). To do that, range over it and append its 1D slice elements to a 1D slice (`[]string`). Then use this 1D slice as an element of the final `data` 2D slice.

For example:

```
developers := [][]string{
    {"first developer"},
    {"second developer"},
}
var devs []string
for _, v := range developers {
    devs = append(devs, v...)
}

data := [][]string{
    devs,
    {"first project", "second project"},
    {"third project", "forth project"},
}
fmt.Println(data)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JT7Z1GsC89n)):

```
[[first developer second developer] [first project second project] [third project forth project]]
```